# Bad pattern while changing input model from code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm trying to impliment some CRUD page with AngularJS. So i have input with some  validation requirements

```
<input ng-class="addForm.country.$error.pattern?'bad-input-border':''"
       name="country"
       ng-model="adding_element.country"
       type="text"
       pattern="[A-Za-z]+"
       class="form-control">
```

Pattern that match only letters. 
Also i have bingding model with that input.

The problem is: when i change input value directly on page, validation works fine `addForm.country.$valid == true`; but when i'm trying to change my model from code i get `addForm.country.$valid == false` even if data is valid.

I changing model on button click, that get generated element from my controller:

```
$scope.generate_country = function()
{
   $http.get("/index.php/cars/generate").then(function(response){
      $scope.adding_element.country = response.data.item.Country;
   });
};
```

The result in `response.data.item.Country` is string. It fails input pattern when i click the button, but when i CTRL+C CTRL+V generated result in input it's OK.

How can i solve that? TIA!

Comment: can you post also the code where you change your model?

Comment: @quirimmo did that.

Comment: Works fine in this [DEMO in PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/dbnM9KhmBYpMZpcYsMzo?p=preview). Please verify that the data from the server is valid.

Comment: @georgeawg thanks. Not valid data did the problem.